# Get and modyfy java source from my own ROM(GalaxyS2)?

Tags: android, eclipse, rom

i have a custom ROM for my device and i want to change one void stored in framework:
"/frameworks/base/wifi/java/android/net/wifi/p2p/WifiP2pService.java"

Is it possible to do it through Eclipse or my be enother way?

Many thanx.

Comment: do you have the source file?

Comment: no, i want to get it from the ROM

Comment: They won't be n the phone itself.